# Relative layout always seems to work for only drawer layout or frame layout, both child doesn't work together

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a relative layout in which i have two child .one is drawer layout and the other is a frame layout in which i have used a fragment .The problem is when i keep drawer layout in the top and the frame layout in the bottom,drawer layout doesn't work and if do the opposite,frame layout doesn't

this is my relative layout

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    layout="@layout/mtoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.example.rohit.newmastervocab.FloatingFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragmentfloating"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" /> 
</FrameLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist1"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:entries="@array/navigation_items"
        android:background="#F3F6C8"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </ListView>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You want the FrameLayout listed first _inside_ the DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Mike M. is absolutely right: you need to keep `FrameLayout` as one of the Children of `DrawerLayout`.

I've updated your XML a bit, take a look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <fragment
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.example.rohit.newmastervocab.FloatingFragment"
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist1"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:entries="@array/navigation_items"
        android:background="#F3F6C8"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now drawer works just as expected and `Fragment` is stick to the bottom|center of the screen.